# Lua returning output after subprocess

Tags: lua, libuv, luvit

Working in lua, I have a table of key/value pairs

```lua
local fmtsToRun = { 
  name = function() 
    return configSubTable
  end
}
```

Which could be 1 or more entries in length. I need to loop through each entry and run a subprocess (through some libuv C bindings).

With a normal for loop, the subprocess results from libuv return after the loop has finished running, leading to things showing up out of order. The result would be

- Loop Start
- Loop Entry 1
- Job 1 starts
- Loop Entry 2
- Job 2 starts
- Loop Ends
- Job1 Returns
- Job2 Returns

What I need to have is

- Loop Start
- Loop Entry 1
- Job 1 starts
- Job1 Returns
- Loop Entry 2
- Job 2 starts
- Job2 Returns
- Loop Ends

I've also tried writing my own version of `pairs()` to and using something like coroutines to handle the callbacks

```lua
for fmt, output in jobIterator(fmtsToRun) do
  print('finished running', output)
end


  local function jobIterator(tbl)
    return coroutine.wrap(function()
      local fmtConf, fmtName
      fmtName, fmtConf = next(tbl, fmtName)
      if nil~=fmtConf then
          local conf = fmtConf()
          local output = nil
          -- wrapper util from Libuv library
          local job = Job:new({
              cmd = conf.cmd,
              args = conf.args,
              on_stdout = onStdout, -- process output
              on_stderr = onStderr, -- process any error
              on_exit = function()
                coroutine.yield(fmtName, output)
              end
          })
          job.send(conf.data)
      end
    end)
  end
```

which leads to this error messages.

```
attempt to yield across C-call boundary
```

What would be the "right" way to wait for the `job` to finish and continue the loop while maintaining the correct order?

Comment: I'd just use os.execute() instead of coroutine.  That way you're guaranteed that the current process will finish in the desired order before starting a new task.

Answer (score 0):

A better option was to manually control the flow and recursively call a function to step through the table one entry at a time.

```lua
local runner = {}
for _, output in pairs(fmtsToRun) do
  table.insert(runner, output)
end
jobIterator(runner)

local function jobIterator(tbl)
  local F = {}
  function F.step()
    if #tbl == 0 then
      return
    end
    local current = table.remove(tbl, 1)
    F.run(current)
  end
  
  function F.run(conf)
    local output = nil
    -- wrapper util from Libuv library
    local job =
      Job:new(
      {
        cmd = conf.cmd,
        args = conf.args,
        on_stdout = onStdout, -- process output
        on_stderr = onStderr, -- process any error
        on_exit = function()
          -- do what you need with output
          print(output)
          F.step()
        end
      }
    )
    job.send(conf.data)
  end

  F.step()
end
```